# ruby-aws-sdk record persists after delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-ruby

I'm trying to delete object from aws s3 via key

```rb
key = "vocs_direct%25252F2021-09-14%25252Fd4c494cc-48a5-4fbd-b6ea-712a8d0b8c55.mp3"
AWS_S3_BUCKET.object(key).delete
```

and I get a succesful response

```
[Aws::S3::Client 204 0.231299 0 retries] delete_object(bucket:"voctag-dev-jonas",key:"vocs_direct/2021-09-14/d4c494cc-48a5-4fbd-b6ea-712a8d0b8c55.mp3")
```

but the thing is the record is still there. I can access it via url, or try deleting again with same response. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after tinkering I've found the issue
In my database slashes are enconded as `%252F` but in aws they are encoded `%2F`
So, since keys were different, it could not delete the record!